# Electron.js and webpack with Creact-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, create-react-app

I wanted to use webpack in electron.js project with react.js

And I started a project with cra. I got some vulnerabilities for some reason, so I deleted node_modules folder and yarn.lock and reinstalled. When I did "yarn start", the error that when using cra, I should not use webpack.

```
[0] There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
[0] It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
[0] 
[0] The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
[0] 
[0]   "webpack": "4.41.5"
[0] 
[0] Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
[0] However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:
[0] 
[0]   /user/name/programming/electron/asdf/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.41.6) 
[0] 
[0] Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
[0] 
[0] If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
[0] That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
[0] 
[0] To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
[0] 
[0]   1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
[0]   2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
[0]   3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
[0]   4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
[0] 
[0] In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
[0] If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
[0] 
[0]   5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
[0]      This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
[0] 
[0]   6. Check if /is/private/programming/electron/qwerty/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
[0]      For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
[0] 
[0]   7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
[0]      This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
[0] 
[0] If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
[0] That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
[0] 
[0] P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
[0] 
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! errno 1
[0] npm ERR! electron-react-typescript-boilerplate@0.2.5 react-start: `react-scripts start`
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[0] npm ERR! 
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the electron-react-typescript-boilerplate@0.2.5 react-start script.
[0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0] 
[0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[0] npm ERR!     /nooo/oooo/.npm/_logs/2020-02-26T13_13_02_140Z-debug.log
[0] cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start exited with code 1
```

This error occurred because I installed webpack manually. So, I delete webpack, but I think I need webpack. Is there a way to use webpack in electron.js, with cra, without ejecting or using another bundler.

PS I'm also using typescript.

Answer (score 1):

This involves quite some configuration steps. To make electron work with `create react app` without ejecting, follow these steps:

### 1) Install packages

```
npx create-react-app
npm install --save-dev electron
```

### 2) Add main process for electron **src/main.js**

Use a [basic example](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js) and modify the `loadURL`.

**local development**

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
```

**production**

```
const startUrl = url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
});
mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
```

### 3) Add a `main` entry to package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron ."
  }
}
```

### 4) Run

Run these commands in different consoles. Wait for react server to start and then start electron.

```
npm run start
npm run electron
```

### 5) Make electron available in react app

```
const electron = window.require('electron');
const fs = electron.remote.require('fs');
const ipcRenderer  = electron.ipcRenderer;
```

For more details and common problems you might want to look into this [freecodecamp tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/).

If you run into problems with the communication between main process and renderer, you might want to adjust the webpack config anyway. You should have a look into [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) before using eject.

Comment: he started project with create react app and wants to use electron without ejecting. I explained how it works. If you have a better answer go ahead.